# It is not possible to train a neural network compute xor

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

please tell me what I did wrong, why the accuracy does not increase?
I tried everything, added layers, increased and decreased the number of iterations, even tried to install dropout (even though I do not have retraining here), but it does not work out :(

```
from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.layers import Dropout

np.random.seed()

NB_EPOCH = 100
VERBOSE = 1
NB_CLASSES = 2

X_in = [[1,0],[1,1],[0,0],[0,1],[1,1],[0,0],[1,1]]
X_answer = [1,0,0,1,0,0,0]
X_in = np.asarray(X_in, dtype=np.float32)
X_answer = np.asarray(X_answer, dtype=np.float32)
X_answer = np_utils.to_categorical(X_answer, NB_CLASSES)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(300, input_dim = 2, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(300, input_dim = 300, activation='softmax'))
model.add(Dense(2, input_dim = 300, activation='relu'))
#model.summary()

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(X_in, X_answer, epochs=NB_EPOCH, verbose=VERBOSE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are only 4 possible outcomes from XOR operation, I have changed your source a bit, so it works just fine now, however requires a few hundred iterations to get to learn the necessary stuff:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import numpy as np

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.layers import Dropout

np.random.seed()

NB_EPOCH = 1000
VERBOSE = 1
NB_CLASSES = 2

X_in = [[1,0],[1,1],[0,0],[0,1]]
X_answer = [[0,1],[1,0],[1,0],[0,1]]
X_in = np.asarray(X_in, dtype=np.float32)
X_answer = np.asarray(X_answer, dtype=np.float32)
#X_answer = np_utils.to_categorical(X_answer, NB_CLASSES)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(10, input_dim = 2, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

#model.summary()

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(X_in, X_answer, nb_epoch=NB_EPOCH, verbose=VERBOSE)

print model.predict( X_in )
```

the result is:

```
Epoch 995/1000
4/4 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.1393 - acc: 1.0000
Epoch 996/1000
4/4 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.1390 - acc: 1.0000
Epoch 997/1000
4/4 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.1387 - acc: 1.0000
Epoch 998/1000
4/4 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.1385 - acc: 1.0000
Epoch 999/1000
4/4 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.1383 - acc: 1.0000
Epoch 1000/1000
4/4 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.1380 - acc: 1.0000
[[ 0.00492113  0.9950788 ]
 [ 0.99704748  0.0029525 ]
 [ 0.99383503  0.00616499]
 [ 0.00350395  0.99649602]]
```

which is really close to the required `[0,1],[1,0],[1,0],[0,1]` (X_answer)

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few problems here. No, it's not impossible (*)

Dropout has nothing to do with your problem (**). You're using a softmax and then a relu? That seems odd to me.  Why are you casting to categorical? Why are you using such a big network when you have such small input examples (10 samples, but 300 paramters on the hidden layer)?

From [here](https://gist.github.com/stewartpark/187895beb89f0a1b3a54), a minimal example of xor with keras:

```
X = np.array([[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]])
y = np.array([[0],[1],[1],[0]])

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(8, input_dim=2))
model.add(Activation('tanh'))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

sgd = SGD(lr=0.1)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd)

model.fit(X, y, show_accuracy=True, batch_size=1, nb_epoch=1000)
print(model.predict_proba(X))
```

---

(*) You're using a multilayer perceptron, but the title grabbed my attention because there's a (relatively) famous proof that an NN without a hidden layer can't learn xor. [Proof example here](https://www.quora.com/Why-cant-the-XOR-problem-be-solved-by-a-one-layer-perceptron)

(**) Dropout helps with generalization when you have deep networks. This is vital when training large models to detect complex high dimensional structures like humans in images. It is going to make your life a lot more difficult when trying to fit xor.